# Any way to speed up an append of data to SDE database while it is still versioned?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, append

My group works on a database and about once a month I receive data that must be appended. This process has required me to reconcile and post all versions to default. I then pull down the database locally and delete all relationship classes and geometric network so I can append to the new data. Then I re-upload database, register data, recreate versions and grant privileges. Is there any way around this process?

Comment: How much data is being appended (relative to the data already in the table)? Have you ever tried to append the data without going through these gyrations? What version of ArcGIS are you using?  Which RDBMS are you using? Please edit the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "append"? If you do not touch the database schema, you should have no issues, just add the data to the default version and it will propagate to all other versions.